# Apache Nifi transform with JoltTranform processor

Tags: json, apache, apache-nifi, jolt

I have some attributes myId, count. Now with these attributes I want write down the Jolt format to get the following output.

```
{
  "projectId": "projectId",
  "ticketId": "NO_TICKET",
  "trigger": "SCHEDULED_BACKLOG",
  "timestamp": 1539060316494,
  "pivotVersion": 1,
  "pivotType": "FlattenedTodoStats",
  "todoCount": "todoCount",
  "pivots": [
    {
      "state": "BACKLOG",
      "type": "NA"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use **Jolt Transform (or) ReplaceText** processors for this case.

As you are having some attributes to the flowfile so use ReplaceText processor
[image]

In ReplaceMent Value configure as

```
{
    "projectId": "${projectId}",
    "ticketId": "${ticketId}",
    "trigger": "${trigger}",
    "timestamp": "${timestamp}",
    "pivotVersion":"${pivotVersion}",
    "pivotType":"${pivotType}",
    "todoCount":"${todoCount}",
    "pivots[]": {
      "*": {
        "state": "${state}",
        "type": "${type}"
      }
    }
}
```

Substitute all the **attribute names(${projectId}..etc) with your attribute names**.

Use **Replacement Strategy** as **AlwaysReplace**

**(or)**

If you want to use Jolt for this case then

Use **default** operation to replace **your attribute values** and prepare `json message`

***Example:***

[image]
**Jolt Specification**

```
[{ "operation": "shift", "spec": { "z":"z" } }, { "operation": "default", "spec": { "projectId": "${projectId}", "ticketId": "${ticketId}", "trigger": "${trigger}", "timestamp": "${timestamp}", "pivotVersion":"${pivotVersion}", "pivotType":"${pivotType}", "todoCount":"${todoCount}", "pivots[]": { "*": { "state": "${state}", "type": "${type}" } } } }]
```

As i don't have any attribute values, so my output json is having all empty values in it.

Change the spec jolt spec as per your requirements.

Comment: @HarshSharmaKhandal, Great, Glad to hear that :) Could you please accept the answer to close this thread..!! https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer